# How to return an error from Cloud Functions to Vue client?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, async-await, google-cloud-functions

In my Vue app, the user enters their billing information, which I then pass into a Google Cloud Function, which updates the customer object in Stripe. My question is, if something goes wrong in the function, how can I return the error, so that I can display an error message to the user?

Here is the actual function...

```
exports.updateStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const { details, customerId } = data;
  const uid = context.auth.uid;

  try {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.update(customerId, {
      name: details.name,
      email: details.email,
      address: {
        line1: details.line1,
        line2: details.line2,
        city: details.city,
        state: details.state,
        postal_code: details.postCode,
        country: details.country
      }
    });

    return;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', err.message, err);
    return err;
  }
});
```

Then, on the client:

```
const updateCus = projectFunctions.httpsCallable('updateStripeCustomer');
const res = await updateCus({ 
  details: profile.value.details,
  customerId: profile.value.billing.customerId
});

console.log(res)
```

The function works correctly, but if at any point Stripe returns an error, I can see it on the client console, but the console.log(res) doesn't even run...

What's the correct way of returning an error, so that I can examine res and output an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below line is good enough to tell the client about the error; you shall remove `return err;`

> throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', err.message, err);

whenever you throw an error `functions.https.HttpsError` you have to catch it on the client side too. As you are using `async/await`, wrap your code inside try/catch block.

```js
try {
    const res = await updateCus({ 
       details: profile.value.details,
       customerId: profile.value.billing.customerId
     });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```